# Did Rex participate in the Great Jedi Purge?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

Captain Rex, aka CT-7567, was the leader of Anakin Skywalker's battalion of Clone Troopers during The Clone Wars.  In *Revenge of the Sith*, after Anakin has been rechristened Darth Vader (but before he dons the familiar costume), he leads a large group of Troopers to the Jedi temple and begins the purge.

While we know that

> Rex removed his inhibitor chip, as we learned on *Star Wars: Rebels*

I don't think we know if that happened before or after the purge began.  Is there any canon reference or source indicating whether or not Rex was still in charge of Anakin/Vader's battalion of Troopers when he sacked the Jedi Temple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Rex Removed the inhibitor chip *before* Order 66.

As detailed in the Star Wars: Rebels episode ["The Lost Commanders"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Commanders), Rex and his friends (Wolffe and Gregor) removed their control chips before Order 66, and thus were unaffected.

The key dialogue:

> **I didn't betray my Jedi**. Wolffe, Gregor, and I **all removed our
>   control chips**. We all have a choice.

As the chip forced compliance, it would have had to have been removed prior to Order 66 for Rex to have not betrayed his Jedi.

Comment: It says that they removed their control chips. It doesn't seem to say *when*.

Comment: @Valorum "I didn't betray my Jedi. Wolffe, Gregor, and I all removed our control chips. We all have a choice."

Comment: @Axelrod well, given that "his Jedi" was in fact Anakin himself, **not** betraying him could be taken to mean that he did participate in the purge.  Regardless, I interpret that statement the same way you do, that Rex took the chip out prior to the purge and didn't kill the Jedi.  Thank you for the reference scene!

Comment: @Axelrod  That's fair enough. You have my +1

Comment: I guess with what we see in the last episode of Clone Wars to this day, "Shattered" (7x11), this answer is not right anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Dave Filoni gave us an answer at Star Wars Celebration Europe 2016, although it isn't the clearest one. He said that towards the end of the in-universe Clone Wars (as in when Anakin goes off to save Palpatine above Coruscant), Anakin gave Ahsoka her own legion, led by Rex. They went off to fight Darth Maul as the events of *Revenge of the Sith* unfolded. This explains why they weren't in that film. However, Dave explains that the events of that story this story were not *technically* canon. However, to Dave and Lucasfilm Story Group's Pablo Hidalgo those events are canon, so they are written in *Star Wars Rebels* as such.

Comment: How is that possible? Ahsoka left the Jedi at the conclusion of her criminal trial during the *Clone Wars* series.

Comment: @Ellesedil Even if she left the Jedi, I see no reason Anakin couldn't have given her temporary control over a Clone Battalion. And it's kind of a shame we never got to see Ahsoka, Rex, and a Clone Legion hunting down Darth Maul in the series.

Comment: @SydneySleeper Looks like that might be just what we get in season 7.  Fingers crossed!

Answer (score -1):

During the Events of “Revenge of the Sith”, Rex was with Ahsoka during “The Siege of Mandalore”. Rex and a few other clones found out about the inhibitor chips implanted in every Republic clone from the beginning of their birth stages. Before “Order 66" took effect, a clone trooper named “Fives”, who was a close friend of Rex and member of the 501st During “The Clone Wars” had proof of the clones being compromised for an unknown reason (Which was Palpatine’s plan to establish the Empire as Darth Sidous in secret and make sure that the Jedi Order would not be a problem in the foreseeable future).
 Watch “Star Wars The Clone Wars S6E1-S6E4" to see what occurs with Fives, This is one of the many best story arcs in the shows run. Fives started out in “Domino Squad” and by the time of “The Battle of Kamino”, got Rex’s interest in him as a member of the 501st.

Back to Rex, since he had his inhibitor chip taken out, he was not affected by “Order 66". He helped Ahsoka escape Mandalore, and eventually ran into “Wollfe” and “Gregor”. If i am not mistaken, Rex tried to convince Commander Cody of the Discovery, but did not listen. Because in Cody’s mind, without the chips implanted, the clones loyal to the Republic would be no better than someone such as Jango Fett or the clones themselves would start turning against “The Republic”.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange. Your answer is good, but we tend to like answers to contain some quotes or references. Also, using paragraphs is really helpful for readability, and tends to result in a better reception. :)